# system design - create class structure for cars - Object Oriented

Tags: oop, architecture, object-oriented-analysis, system-design

So i came across one question recently for system design. 
As per given design below, we have 3 cars out of which 2 of them can have auto pilot and 2 of them can have auto launch

So the question is - how will you design the class structure. Also 
Provide a sample method of lets say, Launch for Suv and provide Unit Test

[image]

So - to answer that, i came up with something like as mentioned below:

```
public class BaseCar
{
    // all common properties
    int height, width, length;
    string color etc.   
}

public class Suv : BaseCar
{
    LaunchCar LaunchSuv {get; set;}

    // Lets say we use DI to inject ctor
    Suv(IAutoLaunch autoLaunch)
    {
        LaunchSuv = autoLaunch;
    }

}

Interface IAutoLaunch
{
    bool Launch();
}

public class LaunchCar : IAutoLaunch
{
    // ctor based on car type
    LaunchCar(CarType)
    {
    }

    // Implementation of Launch based on Car Type

    bool Launch()
    {
        // successfully launch car here..
        return true; 
    }

}
```

So at the End, lets say we want to Launch Suv, then
in that case we can do something like, LaunchSuv.Launch();

- i am not sure if my solution is in correct direction. And if it is, is there any room of improvement?

FYI - the reason i decided to have separate Interface for AutoPilot and AutoLaunch, is because there is always one car out of 3 which doesn't have both feature requirement. If i declare both the methods, in base car, unnecessary all of the cars will have both methods which i don't want - not sure if this reason is good design or not so important!! *Also i have just taken SUV for example, similar class structure can be derived for Sedan and Coupe*

Answer (score 2):

There's no "correct" answer in this context, really. Any architecture-wise decision is considered good if it works for given problem, even better if it's scalable, agile, etc. Same design might be bad for another problem.

So it comes down to a question: "What are expected feautres for you software and how hard would they be to implement using given design?". Because there's no context for your problem (by context I mean "bigger picture"), you can't answer this question.

Comment: I agree with the fact that "correct" is subjective - but idea of discussing here is to have exchange of knowledge. Given problem statement is the picture you have, and asked to design - how wold you do it? :)

Comment: @vran sorry, should've mentioned it explicitly, I've implied that I agree with your design keeping in mind my answer. It's just I hoped for a bit more complex example of usage, then I'd have a bit different opinion on the design

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your approach. The recipe is to have:

- a base class, where you implement the core functionalities
- an interface for each feature (auto-launch is imaginable for ships as well, which is currently out of scope, but in the future your design will support non-cars as well if you define your interfaces wisely)
- a subclass of the base class for each valid feature combination

Comment: my approach was towards leveraging decorator pattern but then i thought it may not be required and i didn't want to over engineer the solution. But i think we both are on the same page here!!

Comment: @vran, yes, we are. If you think this post answers your question, then you can accept it by clicking on the checkbox below the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, AutoLaunch and AutoPilot, can be considered as a 'feature' of BaseCar and can be part of it with default value as false.
Then whichever CarType has any of these can 'implement' that interface which will override the default value.
Rest it depends on the designer/architect, how he/she wants to proceed and how much flexibility they want.

Comment: Having AutoLaunch & AutoPilot on baseCare wouldn't be great in terms of flexible and scalable design. What would happen lets say you want to add other 'N' diff features. Also i am not sure if one should embrace 'flag' based design, my 2 cents!